# Torque Equation

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque

There are two torque equations.

[image]

and

[image]

I'm confused about when to use which one given a certain scenario.

Comment: You can use both together depending on the setup and which quantities are given. For a more helpful answer you'll have to ask in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\tau = rF\sin\theta$ is the equation that you use to determine how much torque is being applied to some object.  $\tau = I\alpha$ is the equation that you use to determine the angular acceleration of a given object once you know how much torque is being applied to it.

Comment: A diagram illustrating $\theta$ wouldn't go amiss here.

Answer (score 0):

- The second equation $\tau = F (r \sin \theta)$ gives you the equipollent torque needed to balance a force $F$ acting with a moment arm (perpendicular distance) of $r \sin \theta$. Not only forces needed to be summed for balance but also the corresponding torque values (moment of force) that result from the line of action of the forces being offset from the summation point.
- The first equation $\tau = I \alpha$ is an equation of motion, a result of the fact the net torque equals the rate of change of angular momentum, $\tau = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} ( L ) = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} ( I \omega ) = I \alpha$. The summation point *must be* the center of mass in this case.

Both equations are used together this this form $$ F (r \sin \theta) = I \alpha $$ to find the angular acceleration due to an offset force in dynamics, and in statics the r.h.s. is zero so the above is $$ F (r \sin \theta) = 0 $$